# String Date validation return incorrect validation

Tags: c#, datetime, .net-6.0

I have date coming in string in format `28042022` `DDMMYYYY` which I then convert to 28/04/2022 using following code

```
public static string MultiInsert(this string str, string insertChar, params int[] positions)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str.Length + (positions.Length * insertChar.Length));
    var posLookup = new HashSet<int>(positions);
    for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
    {
        sb.Append(str[i]);
        if (posLookup.Contains(i))
            sb.Append(insertChar);

    }
    return sb.ToString();

}
```

up to this point is all good but then following code don't return me correct `bool` for validation

```
public override ValidationStatus Validate(string Text)
{
    ValidationStatus validationStatus = new ValidationStatus();

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Text))
    {
        int[] index = { 1, 3 };

        var date = StringExtensions.MultiInsert(Text, "/", index);

        DateTime tempDate;

        var isDateValid = DateTime.TryParseExact(date, "dd/MM/YYYY", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out tempDate);

    }

    return validationStatus;
}
```

Comment: What's the point of inserting the slashes? Just use "ddMMyyyy" as the format when parsing.

Comment: still getting false

Comment: Note that you should be using "y" rather than "Y" for year. The documentation makes no indication that "Y" is valid for year. I did indicate that before but you may not have noticed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use incorrect format (for years).

Change this:

```
"dd/MM/YYYY"
```

to this:

```
"dd/MM/yyyy" // lowercase Y
```

Comment: still getting false for 28042022 by using following code

Comment: var stringDate = StringExtensions.MultiInsert(Text, "/", index);

                DateTime tempDate;

                var isDateValid = DateTime.TryParseExact(stringDate, "ddMMyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out tempDate);

Comment: @K.Z I guess you don't need to insert slashes since you use the format without them.

Comment: @K.Z if you insert slashes then format - `dd/MM/yyyy`, without slashes - `ddMMyyyy`. From your comment you try to insert slashes, but use format without them (which is different from question)